# How to wait for loading to disappear and then click in the button using protractor (error element not clickable)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I have to click at the button using  protractor and GoogleDrive, but the problem is I have a loading before this click. So I have to wait for the loading disappear and then I could click at the button.
The error protractor keep me given is:

The error is:

> Element ... is not clickable at point (111, 145). Other element would receive the click: ...
>       (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
>       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

I already tried to maximize the window using `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();`
but it didn't work

The loading's xpath is:

`/html/body/application/app-loading/loading/div/section/div`

I tried use

```
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeclickable(element), 1000))
```

but it didn't work too because the element is clickable and visible but there is the loading.

I've tried with no success.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(btnNovo).perform().then( () => {
                btnNovo.click().then(() => {
```

What other options do I have?

Comment: I've used browser.sleep(3000) and it's worked but I really don't want to use it

Comment: `browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(btnNovo), 3000)` seems the right approach. Try to increase that browser.wait-timeout to more than 1 sec (as this might be the issue). If that doesn't work please provide more of your test case and the steps you execute. If the `loading` appears on all pages, you could create your own `browser.wait(EC-function)`, which you can call from anywhere and it will always wait until `loading` disappears... let me know, if that could be an approach, so I provide more info for that.

Answer (score 0):

First use, waiting invisiblity of the element for number of TimeoutMiliseconds:

```
browser.wait( EC.invisibilityOf( $('#selector') ), TimeoutMiliseconds );
```

And then for clicking if you want to click at the correct point javascript executor always helps:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",element);
```

Comment: The JSE click will click the element whether the loading screen is up or not. There's no point in waiting for loading to disappear and then using the JSE click. I would recommend not using the JSE click because it will allow the script to click things that a user cannot typically click. Selenium was designed to only interact with elements that a user can interact with... visible, clickable, etc. Do your wait for the loading to be invisible and then just do a normal Selenium click and it should work.